# How to use Javascript namespacing in Protractor automation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have 3 files i.e. conf.js , actionwords.js, project_test.js.
 Actionwords.js and project_test.js are the files generated from hiptest tool.So i need to use this structure for automating test case. When I run through cmd, I am getting error.

I ran:

```
protractor conf.js
```

Message:
  **Failed: Cannot read property 'theApplicationURL' of undefined**

Stack:
  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'theApplicationURL' of undefined**

// conf.js

```
exports.config = {
 framework: 'jasmine2',
 directConnect: true,
 seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
 specs:['path to/project_test.js'],
 capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome' }
 };
```

//actionwords.js

```
var Actionwords = {
theApplicationURL: function () {
browser.get('localhost');
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.sleep(5000);
   },
};
```

//project_test.js

```
describe('Test', function () {
beforeEach(function () {
this.actionwords = Object.create(Actionwords);
});

it('Login_Test (uid:fe6d6670-a864-4d0f-a867-3faf9f51ff8d)', function () {
// Given the application URL
this.actionwords.theApplicationURL();
});
});
```

Can anyone Help me in this ?

Comment: change  your actionwords into a function instead of object and export it, then use it in project_test.js using require()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it this way:

```
var actionwords = {
  theApplicationURL: function () {
    browser.get('localhost');
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.sleep(5000);
  },
};

module.exports = actionwords;
```

test:

```
var actionwords = require("actionwords.js")

describe('Test', function () {
  it('Login_Test (uid:fe6d6670-a864-4d0f-a867-3faf9f51ff8d)', function () {
    // Given the application URL
    actionwords.theApplicationURL();
  });
});
```

**REACTION ON COMMENT about `this`:**

You can assign it to this scope in `beforeEach`:

```
var actionwords = require("actionwords.js")

describe('Test', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    this.actionwords = actionwords;
  });
  it('Login_Test (uid:fe6d6670-a864-4d0f-a867-3faf9f51ff8d)', function () {
    // Given the application URL
    this.actionwords.theApplicationURL();
  });
});
```

Comment: To be specific: Failed: Cannot read property 'theApplicationURL' of undefined 

Got this..

Comment: Message:
  Failed: actionwords.theApplicationURL is not a function

Comment: Updated again, you need to export as well

Comment: luboskrnac : Thanks for the answer.It is working.. But I cannot change my test file. The reason is I am exporting it from a tool. So suppose there are 60000 test cases I can't change my test file for each it.


I need to keep it as                            this.actionwords.theApplicationURL();

Comment: So i can't remove this from actionwords.theApplicationURL(); because that is the structure I am getting from a tool. Can you help me more on this please.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In `beforeEach(...)`, `this` refers to the anonymous function passed to it. The same goes for `it(...)`.

**Declaring a variable in the scope of `describe`**

```
describe('Test', function() {
    var actionwords = Object.create(Actionwords);

    it('Login_Test (uid:fe6d6670-a864-4d0f-a867-3faf9f51ff8d)', function() {
        actionwords.toApplicationURL();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried . But didn't worked.

 ReferenceError: Actionwords is not defined

Comment: Which line? When calling 'Object.create' or when  calling 'actionwords.toApplicationURL'?

Comment: declare `var Actionwords = require("actionwords.js")`

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvaraj  : I did that earlier . Still not working.

Comment: To be specific:
 Failed: Cannot read property 'theApplicationURL' of undefined

Comment: You probably don't export 'Actionwords' from your file (actionwords.js)

Answer (score 0):

Update you `actionword.js` as below,

```
var Actionwords = {
theApplicationURL: function () {
  browser.get('localhost');
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  browser.sleep(5000);
 },
};
module.exports = new Actionwords();
```

And your `project_test.js` will be like,

```
this.actionwords = require("actionword.js");

describe('Test', function () {
 it('Login_Test (uid:fe6d6670-a864-4d0f-a867-3faf9f51ff8d)', function () {
   this.actionwords.theApplicationURL();
 });
});
```

Comment: Your exporting an object not object function. due to which there may be space waste if it not used in test spec.